# How to dependency inject Serilog into the rest of my classes in .NET Console App

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, serilog, .net-5

I'm getting started with [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) but I don't know how to dependency inject the ILogger into my classes. It's easy if I was using ASP.NET Core 5, but I'm using a .NET Core Console App. How can I do similarly?

#### Before with log4net:

```cs
public class TestStrategy
{
    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);

    ...
}
```

#### My Serilog logger creation:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Do I have to DI `logger` into all classes?

Comment: You need to use a dependency injection framework. ASP.NET Core just happens to have a built-in system

Comment: @Xerillio, but there isn't in .NET Console App.

Comment: Exactly. So you need add a DI framework to your project (CastleWindsor, Ninject, Spring.NET, Autofac...)

Comment: @Xerillio, Autofac seems to be the most used, but I gotta learn how to do it rn

Comment: This isn't really a Serilog question. There are lots of Q&As about how to add DI to a console app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example using .net 5 using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`:

#### Program.cs:

```
namespace dotnet.console.app
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Serilog;
    class Program
    {
        static Task Main(string[] args) =>
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();

        static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
                            .AddLogging(builder =>
                            {
                                var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                                            .WriteTo.Console()
                                            .CreateLogger();

                                builder.AddSerilog(logger);
                            }));
    }
}
```

#### Worker.cs

```
namespace dotnet.console.app
{
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                this._logger.LogInformation("Hello, Serilog!");
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 4):

The built-in DI Mechanism in a .Net Core Console Application is available using
**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** package
after DI package installation, configuring services is possible via instantiating a ServiceCollection instance.
Serilog logging functionality can be added as follows.

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                      .AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>()
                      .AddSingleton<IBar, Bar>()
                      .AddLogging(builder =>
                      {
                          var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                          .WriteTo.Console()
                          .CreateLogger();

                          builder.AddSerilog(logger);
                      })
                      .BuildServiceProvider();
```

to have DI configurations encapsulated, configuration can be implemented in a class.

```
public class Startup
        {
            private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
            public Startup()
            {
                ConfigureServices();
            }

            private void ConfigureServices()
            {
                _serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                      .AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>()
                      .AddSingleton<IBar, Bar>()
                      .AddLogging(builder =>
                      {
                          var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                          .WriteTo.Console()
                          .CreateLogger();

                          builder.AddSerilog(logger);
                      })
                      .BuildServiceProvider();
            }

            public ServiceProvider Provider { get { return _serviceProvider; } }
        }
```

Then in the program main method, a new instance of Startup class should be created and starting point implementation can call using the provider property of the startup instance.

```
var startup = new Startup();
        startup.Provider.GetService<IFoo>().DoSomthing();
```

Comment: To  use `AddSerilog` method you also need `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give a complete example with an example class where you DI it

Comment: To be fair, this DI framework isn't any more built-in than the other DI frameworks, but it's probably more lightweight (just a guess though).

Comment: Use `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` for a similar `UseSerilog` method on the host builder. No need to call AddLogging and it sets up all the loggers and providers correctly for a Host

Comment: @Xerillio Actually you are right. As .net core functionality is separated into packages, the DI isn't a built in feature anymore.

Comment: @nop I updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to DI logger into all classes?

No, you don't. Although some may not prefer it, you can choose not to use DI at all for this and just configure the global logger:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

The global logger is automatically accessible to any class that references the `Serilog` namespace, and can be called like this to log an entry:

```
Log.Logger.Information("Hello, world!");
```